# Remove dropdown selector from MIT jQuery clock

Tags: jquery, clock

I found a jQuery clock online (it's brilliant, you should grab it!) but I'd like to display the time without having to select from a dropdown (see example at: http://www.robertmeans.com/clock ). I know absolutely nothing about jQuery. How might I go about modifying this clock so that it just displays the time without having to make a selection? I'd like to be able to put whatever UTC offset I want and make the clock print that time.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jclock.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function() {
       $("#zones_Australia").change(function(){
       if ($('#time-cont .time').length>0){ $('#time-cont .time').remove();}
   var offset = $(this).val();    
       if (offset == '') return;       

   $('#time-cont').append('<div class="time"></div>');

       var options = {
        format:'<span class=\"dt\">%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S</span>',
        timeNotation: '12h',
        am_pm: true,
        utc:true,
        utc_offset: offset
      }

      $('#time-cont .time').jclock(options);
   });
 });
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <select id="zones_Australia">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="-7">US Pacific</option>
  </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
     $(document).ready(
        function() {

           if ($('#time-cont .time').length>0){ $('#time-cont .time').remove();}
//set the offset here       
var offset = -7;    
           if (offset == '') return;       

       $('#time-cont').append('<div class="time"></div>');

           var options = {
            format:'<span class=\"dt\">%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S</span>',
            timeNotation: '12h',
            am_pm: true,
            utc:true,
            utc_offset: offset
          }

          $('#time-cont .time').jclock(options);
     });
```

Comment: Genius! And just like that I'm back to work! Thank you a million times over!